# How to pass a hash of arrays in a subroutine?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, subroutine

I am kinda new to perl and I want to ask how I can pass a hash of arrays in a subroutine. More specifically, I have a hash of arrays

`my %records = (a => [ qw/ A B C / ], b => [ qw/ C D E A / ], c => [ qw/ A C E / ],);`

and I want to apply

```
use Array::Utils qw(:all)
#unique union
my @unique = unique(array1, array2, ..., arrayX);
```

to all the arrays in the hash. I am trying to make a subroutine which will have as input the hash and return the unique union of all the arrays in it. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Thanos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass its [values](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/values.html) (which are array references) and dereference them (as you can see below, inside the [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) function, by prepending the `@` symbol):

```
use Array::Utils qw(:all);
my %records = (a => [ qw/ A B C / ], b => [ qw/ C D E A / ], c => [ qw/ A C E / ],);
my @unique = unique(map {@$_} values %records);
print join(' ',@unique); #will print "A B C D E"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Thano :)